# Adding user controls programmatically

Tags: c#, user-controls

I've recently converted a Web Site in Visual Studio to a Web Application.

I noticed that all the user controls were now strongly typed, however it now seems the only way I can dynamically insert a user control is to use `LoadControl(string)`;

`LoadControl(type,obj[])` used to work by adding a  `<%@ Reference %>` to the page I was adding the user control to, but now this doesn't work either.

Comment: I realize this is an old post but did you solve this?  I am having the same issue now.